# verilog- building a small combinational circuit

Tags: logic, verilog, test-bench

I want to build a small combinational circuit(a few or's, 1 and, 1 not gates), and I stumbled upon a problem in the test bench(maybe even before) and was hoping that someone can help me.

[the circuit is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AlNs.jpg)

This is the code:

```
module hewi(input D3,D2,D1,D0,output A0,A1,V);

  wire k,s; //outputs of the and and not gates
  not N01(k,D2);
  and An1(s,k,D1);
  or Ou1(A0,D3,s);
  or Ou2(A1,D3,D2);
  or Oufinal(V,D3,D2,D1,D0);
endmodule
```

This is the test-bench code

```
module test_benche();

  wire D3,D2,D1,D0,A0,A1,V;
  hewi test(D3,D2,D1,D0,A0,A1,V);

  initial 
  begin
    D3 = 1`b0;
    D2 = 1`b0;
    D1 = 1`b0;
    D0 = 1`b0;
    #50;
    D3=1`b1;
    D2=1`b0;
    D1=1`b1;
    D0=1`b1;
  end
endmodule
```

The problem I receive is that it can't check any one of these expressions:

```
Undefined macro exists as: 'b0'   
  "testbench.sv", 8: token is '`b0'
         D3=1`b0;
                ^
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like you are using backtick ` instead of single quote '

Comment: I corrected my mistake- the next thing it writes after I compile it again is : **Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side
testbench.sv, 15
  Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.
  The offending expression is : D1
  Source info: D1 = 1'b1;** for every one of the expressions i gave values to.

Comment: Next time please add separate question for follow up questions. That way the best answer for each section can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the following error :

> Error-[IBLHS-NT] Illegal behavioral left hand side testbench.sv, 15 Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment. The offending expression is : D1 Source info: D1 = 1'b1

wires can not be assigned in `always` or `initial` blocks. Therefore They need to be converted to `reg` type.

```
//Control signals reg type
reg  D3,D2,D1,D0;
//Outputs driven from DUT wires
wire A0,A1,V;
  hewi test(D3,D2,D1,D0,A0,A1,V);

  initial 
  begin
    D3 = 1'b0;
    D2 = 1'b0;
    D1 = 1'b0;
    D0 = 1'b0;
    #50;
    D3=1'b1;
    D2=1'b0;
    D1=1'b1;
    D0=1'b1;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks! do you have any idea where I can actually see the test bench at work( meaning interactively how the circuit works)?

Comment: Either use `$display` in the testbench to print to command line, or enable waveform dumping to view in waveform viewer.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the fix, missed that.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is because you are using backtick (`) instead of single quotes (')

> All compiler directives are preceded by the (`) character. This
>   character is called grave accent (ASCII 0x60). It is different from
>   the character ('), which is the apostrophe character (ASCII 0x27). The
>   scope of a compiler directive extends from the point where it is
>   processed, across all files processed in the current compilation unit,
>   to the point where another compiler directive supersedes it or the
>   processing of the compilation unit completes. The semantics of
>   compiler directives is defined in [LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) Section 3.12.1 and 5.6.4.